# Acid catalysed dehydration of 5-methylidenecyclopent-2-en-1-ol

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols, hydrocarbons, rearrangements

[image]

I think the following reaction is NOT possible.
[image]

I could not find a mechanism for ring expansion. Is ring expansion possible in any way?

Is the following mechanism correct?
[image]

Comment: Think over resonance b/w charge and pi-bond.

Comment: @RahulVerma I have edited the question based on your comment.

Comment: Ring strain is not very significant here. For ring expansion to occur methanide shift should take place instead of hydride shift which has higher migration amplitude and that too if a primary carbocation forms violating markovnikov rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say your mechanism is acceptable. However, the final product, pentafulvene (PIN: 5-Methylidenecyclopenta-1,3-diene) is said to be not stable at room temperature. Generally, fulvenes are thermally unstable, sensitive to oxygen and photosensitive (Ref.1). They are also prone to acid- and cation-catalysed polymerisations. For example, there have been numerous reports of pentafulvenes undergoing dimerization via Diels–Alder cycloadditions at room temperature similar to that of cyclopentadiene (e.g., Ref.2):

[image: Dimerization of pentafulvenes]

Based on these facts, I'd like to suggest an alternative path for the reaction giving much stable cyclopentaenone derivative:

[image: Alternative path for the reaction]

**References:**

1. Ellen Swan, Kirsten Platts, Anton Blencowe, "An overview of the cycloaddition chemistry of fulvenes and emerging applications," *Beilstein J. Org. Chem.* **2019**, *15*, 2113–2132 (doi:10.3762/bjoc.15.209).
2. Beat Uebersax, Markus Neuenschwander, Hans‐Peter Kellerhals, "Fulven‐Dimere: Synthese, Strukturbeweis and thermisches Verhalten," *Helvetica Chimica Acta* **1982**, *65(1)*, 74-88 (https://doi.org/10.1002/hlca.19820650109).

Comment: It is also likely that the 5-methylcyclopentenone might isomerize via the deconjugated isomer to 2-methylcyclopentenone and then undergo the Diels-Alder.

Comment: @user55119: Yes, it is possible based on the conditions used.

Comment: Is there some aromaticity angle to the instability of fulvene that is, the external pi bond can enter into some kind of conjugation with the internal pi bonds and make an antiaromatic system with 4 pi electrons?

Comment: @Yusuf Hasan: Pentafulvene ($\ce{C6H6}$) is a polarmolecule with carbon-6 is having partial positive charge and carbon-6 is having partial negative charge.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne: I believe you mean carbon-5, the ring for that matter, has a partial negative charge.;)

Comment: @user55119: Yes, that's what I meant. Carbon-6 is exocyclic carbon.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne Does this factor of partial charge so great that in the first step $\ce{H+}$ would prefer to attack the exocyclic $\ce{C}$ instead of electron rich $\ce{O}$ atom?

Comment: Also, as the required temperature is high for dehydration; does this make 5-Methylidenecyclopenta-1,3-diene a stable compound at that temperature? Cyclopentadiene is [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclopentadiene) at high temperature.

Comment: 1) Pentafulvene is produced at last step, so intial protonation has nothing to do with the partial charge; 2) Sure, cyclopentadiene is stable at high temperature, but here, pentafulvene reacts with oxygen as low as $\pu{-35 ^\circ C}$ (Ref. 1). If interested, you should read this paper (PDF available).

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne For 1) I was referring to the mechanism proposed by you where initial protonation occurs at C atom.

Comment: Protonation is in equilibrium including protonation of hydroxy group and double bond. Then, the lowest energy path in next steps wins. If reaction is in thermodynamic control (this reaction is as it is heating), most stable product is the result.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne Is initial protonation permitted in cyclic double bond?